# I Purchased a Domain that Previously had a Google Apps Account. How Do I Re-Create The Google Apps Account or Take Ownership of it?

Tags: google, google-workspace

I recently purchased a domain name.  We'll call it `example.com`.  The previous owner of the domain had a Google Apps account.

Now that I own the domain, I want to create a Google Apps account so I can point the domain `www.example.com` to one of my Google App Engine domains.  We'll call it `application.appspot.com`.

Google App Engine won't allow me to add the domain without verifying ownership by creating a Google Apps account or logging into Google Apps, but I don't have access to the old Google Apps account.

We've tried going to this address to take ownership:

```
https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/example.com/ResetAdminPassword?c=LONG_KEY&hl=en_US
```

We retrieved a new password, but it wouldn't tell us what the login name is.  How do you find out the login name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it out and got the same problem. There doesn't appear to be a way to retrieve the username. I guess you'll have to contact Google about it http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/static.py?page=contacting_support.html

Comment: Do you think maybe they mean the default admin account, "admin".  I tried that.  No luck :(